# Can I uninstall packages using alien or wget?

Tags: uninstall, wget, alien

I used the command wget to download chrome then used alien to install it. is there a way for me to uninstall it using either commands?

the .deb file is ./google-chrome*.deb

Comment: Why does your filename have a wildcard in it? Do you not know the correct name?

Answer (score 3):

`wget` just downloads it and `alien` just converts it to a `*.deb` and optionally installs it on your behalf with `dpkg`. You can use `dpkg -r` or the somewhat more friendly `apt-get remove` to undo that.

```sh
apt-get remove google-chrome
```